# Reset dvd drive region

Tags: dvd

When you setup your dvd drive for the first time it will ask you what reigen you want to set.

Each time you put a dvd from a different reigen into the drive it will ask you to change again.

But you are only allowed to do this 4 times, once you've exhausted that is there any way to change it back ? Or are you now stuck - ie. not able to play dvd's from any other region ?

Comment: AFAIK, the last region change sticks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are willing to research how to flash the firmware of the particular DVD drive in your Mac to change the region, or to make it region-free, I suggest you try the very cool (and free) app [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) from VideoLAN. If VLC does what you need it to, please consider donating to the 'cause'.

Your milage may vary.

Disclaimer: I have no financial stake in VideoLAN.org - I'm just a very satisfied customer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the last region change sticks, so you won't be able to play DVD from another region from then on.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty troublesome to change the region code everytime you load a different DVD. For me, I would choose to make a digital copy of all my DVD collection without region code and then load into DVD drive, it does not ask for region anymore.